# Laravel Permission: (Give User Certain Permissions When They Register)

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking to create a Real Estate App using my Favorite Framework Laravel, I want to have permissions for Landlords, Agents,Admin and Tenant

My Registration Form is Like This

```
<select name="usertype">
        <option>Select Usertype</option>
        <option value="1">Landlord</option>
        <option value="2">Agent</option>
        <option value="3">Tenant</option>
</select>
```

I want to have a single dashboard url for all this users apart from admin i.e landlord,agent and tenant will have `localhost/dashboard` as url but admin would have `localhost/admin` as url.

I want to ask that how can i display different pages or contents for this users i.e landlord,agent,tenant after they make selection during registration.

I hope someone understands me

Answer (score 0):

In controller to show the form

```php
function showForm(){
  $roles = Role::where('name', '!=', 'admin')->get();
  return view('create', compact('roles'));
}
```

Now in your form(e.g. `create.blade.php`):

```php
<select name="role_name">
  <option value="">Select Usertype</option>
  @foreach($roles as $role)
    <option value="1">Landlord</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Then in the controller, may be in `store()` method:

```
public function store()
{
  //Based on your requirements, 'admin' should be changed
  $user->assignRole(request('role_name'));

  if($user->hasRole('admin'){
    return redirect('/admin');
  }
  return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

Comment: i am using a laravel package (spatie) but i do not understand how i can assign role with registration

Comment: oh, ok. Spatie package has far better way to manage this. Updated the answer. Check if it helps.

Comment: how will the form be then, what if user want the role landlord,tenant,agent? how will they select this??

Comment: Sorry, I thought you already knew these things. Updated the answer.

Comment: But i have a registration form already which is the default one that comes with laravel, how do you suggest i do this?

Comment: Default is default. But we have our own requirements. So, we can modify the default one to add the roles dropdown as you just posted in your question.